# Словари спорят: наизготовку и на изготовку. Что нынче с наизготовкой?

Tags: орфография, наречия, словари

> **Орфографический словарь**
>
> на изготовку
>
> **Большой толковый словарь**
>
> **НАИЗГОТОВКУ, *нареч*.** *Разг.* =Наизготове.

[Понятно, что рекомендуется опираться на орф. словарь. Только вот Нацкорпус дает примеров почти поровну:
слитно - 92 вхождения;
раздельно - 85 вхождений.
Получается, что ни один вариант написания не считается неправильным?](http://forum.gramota.ru/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=3956)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С наречием ***наизготовку*** все плохо.

Пользователи русского языка привыкли **к словарю Розенталя, где указано слитное написание этого слова.** И это вполне логично, так как существует пара: ***наизготовку*** (наречие) — ***на изготовку*** (чего-либо, существительное).

http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=68#pp68

http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/2268702-kak-pravilno-pisat-naizgotovku-ili-na-izgotovku.html

**В словаре Ефремовой** дано раздельное написание наречия: [https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/188767/На](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/188767/%D0%9D%D0%B0)

Я полагаю, что такое решение не имеет объяснения.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

В данном случае речь идет **об общеупотребительной, а не о специальной лексике**, а там военные термины ***изготовка, взять на изготовку*** не применяются. (Но зато существует слово изготовка ― изготовление).

В этом отношении  наречие ***наизготовку*** лучше вписывается в общеупотребительную речь, что мы видим из классических произведений (там это НЕ ВОЕННЫЕ КОМАНДЫ, а именно значение "наготове"). И стиль у этого слова скорее нейтральный (просто его значение не соответствует спец. терминологии).

Также  на Грамоте.ру **в правилах Розенталя слитное написание слова** (забыли исправить?).

И вообще, в новых словарях достаточно часто используются поспешные, непродуманные решения, вносящие путаницу в практическое письмо (это уже мое личное мнение).

Примеры:

― В хату ступили двое военных, держа **наизготовку** автоматы. [Виктор Астафьев. Обертон (1995-1996)]

Оружие было взято **наизготовку**, однако до поры до времени не пущено в ход ― всё было по закону. [Василий Аксенов. Круглые сутки нон-стоп // «Новый Мир», 1976]

Answer (score 1):

Я склонен согласиться с объяснением, которое дано в конце обсуждения по ссылке в вопросе. Есть специальный термин в военном деле: **на изготовку**. Пишется раздельно (что подтверждается словарями Розенталя и Кузнецова), и это употребление не является разговорным. Есть разговорное наречие "наизготовку", которое пишется слитно (написание слитно этого наречия также зафиксировано у Кузнецова, Розенталя и в др. словарях).

Answer (score 1):

Я всё же считаю правильными обе формы, но применяемые по-разному в разных контекстах:

1. Взять (брать) оружие НА ИЗГОТОВКУ. Здесь "изготовка" - существительное. Производится ДЕЙСТВИЕ с оружием, приводящее к изготовке. Изготовки ещё нет. Действие приводит к её обретению. Раздельное написание.
2. (Быть, стоять, дежурить) с оружием НАИЗГОТОВКУ. Здесь уже наречие - "наизготовку". Определяетя СОСТОЯНИЕ оружия. Изготовка уже имеет место - оружие находится в состоянии изготовки. Слитное написание.

Кратко:
Действие - "на изготовку".
Состояние - "наизготовку".